# Integrate Ng-Survey multiple time inside the same component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im using ng-surveys template inside my angular application 
https://ng-surveys.firebaseapp.com/
I put the template selector "" inside *ngFor to make multiple surveys in the same page.
It works but the browser considers all the surveys as the same survey : whene I change something in one survey it changes in the other surveys.

I tried to integrate the template dynamicly using Angular ComponentResolver but I faced many errors and I'm not sure this way can fix my problem.
[image: This a screenshots]
[image: This a screenshots]

create-assignment.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o fa-lg"></i> Questionnaires
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                      <tabset>
                          <tab *ngFor="let survey of surveys; let i = index">
                            <ng-template tabHeading><img [src]="survey.category_icon"/> {{survey.category_name}}</ng-template>
                            <!-- <app-create-survey></app-create-survey> -->
                            <!-- <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template> -->
                              <ngs-builder-viewer [options]="options"></ngs-builder-viewer>
                          </tab>
                        </tabset>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

create-assignment.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, Inject, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStoreService } from '../../../shared/services/local-store.service';
import { ApplicationService } from '../../../shared/services/application.service';
import { NgbDateParserFormatterService } from '../../../shared/services/ngb-date-parser-formatter.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { IBuilderOptions, NgSurveyState, IElementAndOptionAnswers } from '../../../shared/ng-surveys/models';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Survey } from '../../../shared/models/survey';
import { LoaderService } from '../../../shared/services/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-assignment',
  templateUrl: './create-assignment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-assignment.component.scss']
})
export class CreateAssignmentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {
  options: IBuilderOptions;
  assignment: any = {};
  pending: Boolean = false;
  user: any;
  shops: any = [];
  survey_categories: any = [];
  surveys: any = [];
  errors: any = {};
  service: any
  @ViewChild('dynamic', { 
    read: ViewContainerRef , static: false
  }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef

  constructor(
    @Inject(LoaderService) service,
    private ls: LocalStoreService,
    public router: Router,
    public toastr: ToastrService,
    private dateService: NgbDateParserFormatterService,
    private appServ: ApplicationService
  ) {
    this.service = service
   }

   ngAfterViewChecked() {
    // this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef)
    // this.service.addDynamicComponent()
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      importSurvey: {
        callback: this.importSurvey.bind(this),
      },
      surveyButtons: [{
        title: 'Sauvegarder questionnaire',
        icon: 'i-Data-Save',
        text: 'Sauvegarder',
        callback: this.saveSurvey.bind(this),
      }],
      importElement: {
        callback: this.importElement.bind(this),
      },
      elementButtons: [{
        title: 'Sauvegarder question',
        icon: 'i-Data-Save',
        text: 'Sauvegarder',
        callback: this.saveElement.bind(this),
      }]
    };
    this.appServ.getSurveyCategories().subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.survey_categories = response.data;
      this.survey_categories.forEach(el => {
        this.surveys.push(new Survey(el.id, el.name, el.icon, this.options));
      });
    });
    this.user = this.ls.getItem('user');
    this.appServ.getBusinessShops(this.user).subscribe((response: any) => {
      this.shops = response.data;
    });
  }

  importSurvey(): Observable<NgSurveyState> {
    // Mocking get request
    return this.getSurvey();
  }

  importElement(): Observable<IElementAndOptionAnswers> {
    // Mocking get request
    return this.getElement();
  }

  getSurvey(): Observable<NgSurveyState> {
    return
  }

  getElement(): Observable<IElementAndOptionAnswers> {
    return 
  }

  saveSurvey(ngSurveyState: NgSurveyState): void {
    console.log(ngSurveyState);
  }

  saveElement(element: IElementAndOptionAnswers): void {
    // Add post request to save survey data to the DB
    console.log('element: ', element);
  }

  toObject = (map = new Map) =>
  Array.from
    ( map.entries()
    , ([ k, v ]) =>
        v instanceof Map
          ? { key: k, value: this.toObject (v) }
          : { key: k, value: v }
    )

}
```

I want to make each survey not similar to other surveys

Answer (score 0):

If you look into source code of that library:

In this file `projects/ng-surveys/src/lib/ng-surveys.module.ts`

These reducers(services) contain survey object:

`NgSurveyStore, SurveyReducer, PagesReducer, ElementsReducer, OptionAnswersReducer, BuilderOptionsReducer` provided under module level injectors if we can provide these in component level injectors data wouldnt be shared.

Since they are provided in module and when you import in your own module, they are sharing single instance of these reducers which store state survey object.